# Mandrill template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mandrill

I am currently working with mandrill mailer I am able to send emails through it.

But I want to add a link to my template that redirect to a particular url of my application that contains a dynamic user id say

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com/1"></a>
```

where 1 is the dynamic user id

I have tried using the variables

```
@url = "http://stackoverflow.com/#{user.id}"
# if subject.present?
# mail(to: user.email, subject: subject)
# else
# mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome to Reditum')
# end
if subject.present?
mandrill_mail(
template: 'user_signup',
subject: subject,
to: user.email,
:global_merge_vars => [
{
name: "confirmation_link",
content: @url,
}],
# to: invitation.email,
# to: { email: invitation.email, name: 'Honored Guest' },
# vars: {
# 'BODY' => @url
# },
important: true,
inline_css: true,

)
```

In my template I am using

```
<a href="*|confirmation_link|*">MyLink</a>
```

But once the email is sent I am not able to click this link.

Please help me out with this